# Roots of (1+x)^n - a= 0, a <> 0, n > 1

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to work out the roots of

$(1+x)^n - a = 0$

This is the characteristic equation of a dynamical system. $a$ is a constant and $n > 1$. If $a=0$ the solutions are straightforward, what about when $a\neq0$? Any pointers to finding the solution would be helpful.

Comment: $<>$ is nonstandard. Use $\neq$ instead.

Comment: That's my pascal programming legacy coming through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move $a$:
$$ (1+x)^n = a
$$
If you write $a = \rho e^{i\phi}$, the solutions are given by
$$ 1 + x = \sqrt[n]{\rho} e^{i\phi/n + i 2\pi k /n}, k \in [0..n-1]
$$
Hence $x = \sqrt[n]{\rho} e^{i\phi/n + i 2\pi k /n} - 1$.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to online material or textbooks that cover this? I'm curious how you came up with the solution so fast, is it well known?

Comment: @rhody It is called $n$th roots of unity, or complex exponential, or De Moivre's formula, or polar form of a complex number.

Comment: It would probably help to think of this in terms of a polygon of $n$ sides, each side subtending an angle of $2\pi /n$ at the center of the circumscribing circle. The coordinates of each point in the argand plane gives the roots. As @HenryW. said, it would be easier to do this in polar coordinates, as we are working with circles. Try to visalise it (draw it or something). The answer should become more comprehensible then.

Comment: Putting a on the other side and taking the n roots should be obvious to anyone.  If a is positive or if a is negative and n is odd and if you are only considering the reals the roots are straight forward.  Those who know complex analysis know the roots of unity.  So yes.  This is well known.

Comment: I've not done any formal classes on complex analysis so I'm learning this as I go along. I could take the nth root on both sides but with out knowledge of complex analysis it didn't lead me anywhere. So I'm not sure it would be obvious to anyone as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, I just realized thanks for getting back.